# How to get audio flux while dialling from the computer(modem) to a mobile phone with JavaComm lib

Tags: java, audio, serial-port, modem

my name is zawadi,I am developping a java application that will be talling the modem to call a phone. I'm working with the JavaComm API to talkwith the serial port. 
I've succeded to send SMS. About making calls, I am facing issues. Right, I am dialling well with the command ATD command. The problem is that, when the phone that is receiving the call is taking down the call, I am not beeing able, neither to get the Audio from the called phone to the computer nor to play the incomming sound on the PC speakers. I'd like some one to help me. Here is my code:

```
package server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.comm.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import static server.recevoirAudio.status;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import static server.recevoirAudio.format;
import static server.recevoirAudio.sourceDataLine;

public class Connect implements SerialPortEventListener,
  CommPortOwnershipListener {


  private String comPort = "COM20"; // Ce Port COM  doit avoir été connecté avec le Modem GSM
  private String messageString = "";
  private CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
  private Enumeration portList;
  private InputStream inputStream = null;
  private OutputStream outputStream = null;
  private SerialPort serialPort;
  AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
  static AudioFormat format;
  static int sampleRate = 16000;
  static DataLine.Info dataLineInfo;
static SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

  /** Creates a new instance of GSMConnect */
  public GSMConnect(String comm) {

this.comPort = comm;


 }

 public boolean init() {
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
      portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
      if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
        if (portId.getName().equals(comPort)) {
            System.out.println("init");
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

public void checkStatus() {
    send("AT+CREG?\r\n");
  }

 public void dial(String phoneNumber) {
 try {
//pour appeller
      messageString = "ATD" + phoneNumber + ";\n\r";
      outputStream.write(messageString.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void send(String cmd) {
    try {
      outputStream.write(cmd.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void sendMessage(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    send("AT+CMGS=\"" + phoneNumber + "\"\r\n");
    send(message + '\032');
  }

 public void hangup() {
    send("ATH\r\n");
  }

  public void connect() throws NullPointerException {
    if (portId != null) {
      try {
        portId.addPortOwnershipListener(this);
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("MobileGateWay", 2000);
      } catch (PortInUseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

  try {
    inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
    outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  try {
    /** These are the events we want to know about*/
    serialPort.addEventListener(this);
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

  } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }


//Register to home network of sim card</p>

  send("ATZ\r\n");

} else {
  throw new NullPointerException("COM Port not found!!");
}

}

public void serialEvent(javax.comm.SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) {
    switch (serialPortEvent.getEventType()) {
      case SerialPortEvent.BI:
      case SerialPortEvent.OE:
      case SerialPortEvent.FE:
      case SerialPortEvent.PE:
      case SerialPortEvent.CD:
      case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
      case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
      case SerialPortEvent.RI:
      case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
      case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:

    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
    format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);
    }`
}
  public void ownershipChange(int type) {
    switch (type) {
      case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_UNOWNED:
        System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_UNOWNED");
        break;
      case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_OWNED:
        System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_OWNED");
        break;
      case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_OWNERSHIP_REQUESTED:
        System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_INUSED");
        break;
    }

  }


}
```

It seams that I am not understanding how to deal with audio in this case. Any directive will really be helpfull

Comment: *"Audio flux"*, *" talling the modem"* -- Huh??  *"I am not ... able ... to get ... sound on the PC speakers."* -- You will not be able to hear any audio from the phone line (e.g. dial tone, dialing tones/pulses, modem negotiation/training noises) unless the modem has an audio output that you connect to the PC's audio adapter/card (e.g. the line-in jack).

Comment: thanks sawdust for your comment. It's cheering!!! I think that I am not exposing clearly my problem. But, by "talling the modem" I just want to explain that, using the "ATD+phonenumber:" my java app is odering the modem to make a voice call to the given number. I am using a simple GSM modem connected on the port "COM23". So, I was thinging that it would be possible to get the incoming voice in an AudioInputStream and than proceed it. What I am not able to do is toknow that the sound from the phone is yet ready on the port. So, am I missunderstanding Something? thanks

Comment: some other two questions, what does this instruction do: AudioInputStream.getAudioInputStream(InpurStream? when does the instruction "case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:" shal be executed?

Comment: *"Talling"* in English makes no sense at all.  It's not a word.  Nor does "audio flux" make sense.  You simply cannot *"hear"* or receive in any way the voice or any audio from a phone or modem unless this analog signal is somehow fed to the PC's audio adapter/card.  The COM port is for RS-232 signals.  If you get an oscilloscope, then you could demonstrate to yourself the different waveforms of RS-232 versus analog voice.

Comment: I am really sorry for those mistakes! About what is in your last comment I'd like to know more. I've been going through reseachs about what is inside, and I conclueded that you are right. but, I still have a lot of incomprehension about these things. I am using a modem that is connected to the USB port, not on the serial port. One question, is there any different way to access the USB port?

Comment: A USB port is a lot more complicated than a RS-232 port, since it's a bus for multiple devices.  Your modem is probably identifying itself as a "communications device", aka CDC ACM, which at the data layer, is just like a RS-232 serial link, i.e. a COM port.  But neither RS-232 or USB can handle an analog audio signal, which is what you want to listen to.  (Nor do modems typically digitize the signal as an audio codec.)  This is a fundamental concept that you really should understand, but may be beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks it's now enought clear than it was. One more question, can the conversion be possible un java? And about that fundemental concept you talk about, would you please give some orientations! even a link shall be helpfull